# Left-right swipe gesture for ViewPager article not working for me?

Tags: android

I've implemented a ViewPager, which serves ImageViews, as demonstrated in this article and source:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java

Rendering is fine, but I get a very strange gesture problem when trying to swipe through the content of the pager. It seems like the left-right swipe gestures don't get captured correctly, so the pager just snaps back to the 0th element. If I keep playing with the gestures, maybe 1 out of 50 times I can get it to advance to the next page.

I'm using this in a ListView (via getListView().addHeaderView(myViewPager)). Other than that, everything is the same. Has anyone else had success with this implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you use viewpager as listview's header ,you need to do this then the viewpager can works fine.

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    PointF downP = new PointF();
    PointF curP = new PointF();
    int act = event.getAction();
    if(act == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || act == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || act == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
      ((ViewGroup) v).requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
      if (downP.x == curP.x && downP.y == curP.y) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```